# Let's encrypt after installing Django has errors

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx

After installing Django I tried to install SSL using Let's Encrypt with Nginx,

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d [mydomain.com]
```

But I get this error,

```
 Domain: [mydomain.com]
 Type:   unknownHost
 Detail: No valid IP addresses found for [mydomain.com]
```

My domain is accessible and there are A entries.

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you get the name resolution with `dig mydomain.com`?

Comment: dig mydomain.com +short showed nothing.

Comment: There you go...`certbot` is correct.

Comment: what is the solution?   why mydomain.com shows the website?

Comment: Did you put it in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: What should I put in /etc/hosts?